# Print using javascript in Fluid browser(mac)

Tags: javascript, macos, browser, printing, fluid

I am using the js code window.print() to perform print functionality. But this is not working in Fluid browser in MAC OS. Its working in all other browsers. Please give me a solution for this.

thnx

Answer (score 0):

seems like you're not the only one having this problem ([see this post in fluidapps google group](http://groups.google.com/group/fluidapp/browse_thread/thread/b47d2edfdaa68fb9/a47bd8b79bedc74)), so i assume this is a bug.

the best way to get a fast and reliable answer is to ask the developers - just click on "support" on [the official website](http://fluidapp.com/) (on the right side below the download/purchase-buttons).